# Making variable sized immutable list in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, immutability, mutability

I try to make a variable sized immutable list in Kotlin, but the only way I found is this. Isn't there a more clean way to do it ?

```
val size = nextInt(0, 50)
val list = mutableListOf<Post>()
for (i in 0..size) {
    list.add(getRandomPost())
}
val immutableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(list)
```

When my source is another list (with random size) I can do `val immutableList = otherList.map{ /* thing that will be add() */ }` but found nothing similar for just integrer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can benefit on kotlin collections extensions and use `List` builder

```kotlin
val list: List<Post> = List(Random.nextInt(0, 50)) {
      getRandomPost()
}
```